# I got message import SVG with ERROR@ <feGaussianBlur> is not supported

Tags: android, android-studio, svg

Android Studio send me message `"ERROR@ <feGaussianBlur> is not supported"`
 and `"ERROR@ <filter> is not supported"` when 
i try import SVG to xml!

I using Inkscape to make and edit SVG file. any solution?

**UPDATE**

Android Studio 3.4.0

vector xml code:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="120dp"
    android:height="70dp"
    android:viewportWidth="120"
    android:viewportHeight="70">
  <path
      android:pathData="m29.87,5.114h81.925c2.212,0 3.312,1.83 2.467,4.104l-19.088,51.359c-0.845,2.274 -3.306,4.104 -5.518,4.104L7.731,64.681c-2.212,0 -3.312,-1.83 -2.467,-4.104L24.352,9.218c0.845,-2.274 3.306,-4.104 5.518,-4.104z"
      android:strokeWidth="0.43320084"
      android:fillColor="#000000"
      android:strokeColor="#00000000"
      android:fillAlpha="1"/>
  <path
      android:pathData="m29.87,4.585h81.925c2.212,0 3.312,1.83 2.467,4.104L95.174,60.048c-0.845,2.274 -3.306,4.104 -5.518,4.104L7.731,64.152c-2.212,0 -3.312,-1.83 -2.467,-4.104L24.352,8.689c0.845,-2.274 3.306,-4.104 5.518,-4.104z"
      android:strokeWidth="0.43320084"
      android:fillColor="#aaffaa"
      android:strokeColor="#00000000"/>
</vector>
```

error message:

ERROR @line 28:  is not supported

ERROR @line 36:  is not supported

Comment: show SVG code, plz

Comment: @VladyslavUlianytskyi i've been add the code.

Comment: I have taken your code, added new drawable with it, lounch up with your drawable -  with no problem! So question is:
"ERROR @line 28: is not supported"
what is it? where you get it? 
new drawable with your code is 18 lines only!

Comment: @VladyslavUlianytskyi i import it from Android Studio using Vectot Assets

Comment: just try to create new drawable and copy-paste xml code there

Comment: @VladyslavUlianytskyi not work eihter. its like Paul LeBeau says.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`<filter>` and `feGuaussianBlur>` are SVG filter elements.  They add bitmap filter effects to SVG elements.

Android VectorDrawables **do not support SVG filters**.

- If you can live without the filter effect (the blur), then edit your SVG file and remove it/them.  Then try importing again.
- If you need the blur effect, then you won't be able to use a VectorDrawable.  You will be forced to use a bitmap image instead.

Comment: also can you help me make ImageView elevation on API < 23?! I make that vector is for making shadow or elevation effect to ImageView. Can you help me to make that effect programnaticaly?

Comment: I believe this method will work on API 17+: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/renderscript/ScriptIntrinsicBlur

Comment: ScriptIntrinsicBlur -This class was deprecated in API level 31.
Renderscript has been deprecated in API level 31. Please refer to the migration guide for the proposed alternatives